# What are some compiler options that I can use to get this disassembly?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, disassembly

**I have found that the executable from the code**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**can be disassembled into** (compiled using gcc -m32)

This code is from another person

```
; Variables:
        ;    arg_4: 12
        ;    arg_0: 8
        ;    var_4: -4
        ;    var_8: -8
        ;    var_C: -12
        ;    var_10: -16
        ;    var_18: -24
push       ebp
mov        ebp, esp
sub        esp, 0x18
call       _main+11
pop        eax                            ; CODE XREF=_main+6

mov        ecx, dword [ebp+arg_4]
mov        edx, dword [ebp+arg_0]
lea        eax, dword [eax-0x1f5b+0x1fa6] ; "Hello World!\\n"

mov        dword [ebp+var_4], 0x0
mov        dword [ebp+var_8], edx
mov        dword [ebp+var_C], ecx

mov        dword [esp+0x18+var_18], eax  ; method imp___symbol_stub__printf
call       imp___symbol_stub__printf
xor        ecx, ecx                           
mov        dword [ebp+var_10], eax
mov        eax, ecx                                    
add        esp, 0x18                           
pop        ebp
ret
```

**but when I disassemble the executable from the same code** (compiled using gcc -m32)

I got a really long dissembly code [(here is the link)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E34DEk3h6Ibz0L1KUU6_0fw4zUYXEq37/view?usp=sharing)

**My questions are**

1. Why are the instructions from the same code different? Or, are they the same?
2. Is there any compiler or compiler option I can use that gives me the disassembly code just like that from the other person?
3. Do you recommend any reference that I can read to understand terms from the long assembly code? (such as __x86.get_pc_thunk.dx)

Best regards,
Tyson

Comment: Are you sure it was not `gcc -m32 -O2` in the first case? I got short code when I compiled with `-O2` and long one when I compiled without it.

Comment: You can disassemble either of the following: `foo.o` created via `gcc -m32 -c foo.c`. Or, `foo` from `gcc -m32 -o foo foo.c`. The first is just the object file and will be shorter, just disassembling the `main` function inside it. The latter is the fully _linked_ executable and will have all functions necessary to run the program, and will be larger. You disassembled the full executable.

Comment: Note that the other person's code called `printf`. But, your compiler converted `printf("Hello world\n");` into `puts("Hello world\n");` These are differences in the compiler and `stdio.h` on both systems.

Comment: Probably _not_ worth hacking `get_pc_thunk` from the executable. _If_ you _really_ want to know, track down the _source_ code for these functions [which should have comments]. This is a bit of a tall order as the origin may be in the compiler, the ELF interpreter, the `ld` linker, or `glibc`. Also, you'll need to learn about linkers, etc. and how they do there job.

Comment: @Craig Wow, thank you for your comments, Craig! I can know understand better. I know see the difference.

Comment: @dyukha Thank you, dyukha! I will try to check if it was -O2 in the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your looking at two different versions of the disassembly.  One is AT&T syntax and the other is Intel. Also, the link has all the assembly and your snippet here just has the main function.
2. The compiler options will change the output and cause more optimization to occur.  Most disassemblers have the ability to switch syntax (I think intel is more common).
3. This is something generated by GCC so that your code can use the dynamically linked libraries that are build into linux/bsd.  The thunk provides a way to resolve the addresses for the [function](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-dynamic-libraries/).